# applet fails to load occasionally

Tags: java, applet

Our applet fails to load 20% of the time in IE 11. I have the logs from the java console - not sure whether a trained eye can spot anything different from the below 2 console logs (successful load vs failed) here.

```
<object name="myViewer"
    type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
    code="myclass.myviewer"
    archive="xyz.jar,abc.jar"
    width=1400
    height=700>
    <param name="permissions" value="sandbox">
</object>
```

**First a successful applet load**

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_35
Using JRE version 1.6.0_35-b10 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@1975b59
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Downloading resource: http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar
    Content-Length: 37,270
    Content-Encoding: null
security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
security: Loading Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts
security: Loaded Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts
security: Loading Deployment certificates from C:\Users\c-joeldenn\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Loaded Deployment certificates from C:\Users\c-joeldenn\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Downloading resource: http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar
    Content-Length: 2,530,810
    Content-Encoding: null
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 185345 us, pluginInit dt 767308 us, TotalTime: 952653 us
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/my/studio/pu/studio.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels_en.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels_en.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels_en.properties with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels_en.properties with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels_en_US.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels_en_US.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels_en_US.properties with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels_en_US.properties with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@1975b59
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
All buttons enabled/disabled...
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@109ea96
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 185345 us, pluginInit dt 3943734 us, TotalTime: 4129079 us
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Skipped starting applet -- terminated abruptly
basic: Starting applet teardown
basic: Finished applet teardown
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@109ea96
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@b51c29
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 185345 us, pluginInit dt 3998108 us, TotalTime: 4183453 us
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@15b0e2c
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 185345 us, pluginInit dt 4080973 us, TotalTime: 4266318 us
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@b51c29
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
All buttons enabled/disabled...
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@15b0e2c
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
All buttons enabled/disabled...
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
loadPDF called: _tt_/10012002.pdf
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/_tt_/10012002.pdf with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/_tt_/10012002.pdf with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/org/mozilla/javascript/RhinoException.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/cmaps/Adobe-Identity-UCS2 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/cmaps/Adobe-Identity-UCS2 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
```

**Here is a log from the failed load**

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_35
Using JRE version 1.6.0_35-b10 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@a20892
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@127734f
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Downloading resource: http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar
    Content-Length: 37,270
    Content-Encoding: null
security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
security: Loading Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts
security: Loaded Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts
security: Loading Deployment certificates from C:\Users\c-joeldenn\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Loaded Deployment certificates from C:\Users\c-joeldenn\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Downloading resource: http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar
    Content-Length: 2,530,810
    Content-Encoding: null
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
basic: Applet loaded.
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 309994 us, pluginInit dt 3415842 us, TotalTime: 3725836 us
security: Start to check whether root CA is replaced
security: The root CA hasnt been replaced
security: No timestamping info available
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 309994 us, pluginInit dt 3418562 us, TotalTime: 3728556 us
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/my/studio/pu/studio.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/MMMM/labels/ViewerLabels_en.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@17c96a9
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/webviewer-20150119.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/MMMM/MYViewer/myViewer.jar
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: requiring Java 6 for applets is a bad idea since there are no more security fixes for it.

Comment: yes, but unfortunately I got to work with this version of Java until the enterprise is moved to a different/later version :(

Comment: Do you have the sourcecode of the applet? If yes, you could check which is the last line of code that gets executed in the failing case by looking for the logging output in the code.